# Change list of objects to properties of an object

Tags: c#, silverlight, casting

I have a list of objects (mainly int, string, double)

And I would like to cast the items of that list into the properties of an object.

The result should look like : MyObject.ItemOfList1 , MyObject.ItemOfList2

How should I implement that ?

Comment: Is MyObject already defined?  Do you just need to use reflection to assign the values or do you want to dynamically create an object based on the content of a list?

Comment: MyObject is not defined. I want to dynamically create an object based on the content of a list

Comment: You'll have to create it in a new assembly using Reflection.Emit. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xxf1410.aspx

Comment: This sounds like a typical XY problem. You'd like to do X to achieve Y, but you haven't told us what Y is... there's almost certainly a better approach to your problem, but you need to tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: More precisely, I'm using telerik's expression editor on a grid so that i can add/substract values of columns. Since my number of columns is dynamic, i use a dictionary<string,obj> to fill the grid. Works fine but the expression editor doesn't accept the dictionnary. But when i used a static object, it's was ok. So i guess that if i cast my list of objects (from my dict) into an object, i'll be able to use it in the expression editor. I hope it's clearer that way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this -

```
 var listobj = new List<object>() { 1, 2, "3", "4", 1.2 };    
 var x = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;

 foreach (var obj in listobj)
 {
      //Add a property dynamically - property name and value
      x.Add(obj.ToString(), obj.ToString());  
 }
```